# MediaWiki API number of results

Tags: java, mediawiki-api

I am using MediaWiki API to get articles. How to increase number of pages returned by the API. As its default value is 10 but I want it to increase it. Can anyone please guide me how to do it?

Comment: Use the `srlimit` query parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If increasing the limit is not enough, you can use the [paging machanism](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries) to continue your query.

Answer (score 0):

As qqilihq said, use the `srlimit` query parameter for the "search" module, or [the appropriate limit parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Lists#Limits) for the others.